# Temperature Converter Challenge

Tags: c

I was doing a coding challenge for a website, the premise was:

> In this challenge, write a program that takes in three arguments, a start temperature (in 
>   Celsius), an end temperature (in Celsius) and a step size. Print out a table that goes from > the start temperature to the end temperature, in steps of the step size; you do not 
>   actually need to print the final end temperature if the step size does not exactly match. 
>   You should perform input validation: do not accept start temperatures less than a lower 
>   limit (which your code should specify as a constant) or higher than an upper limit (which 
>   your code should also specify). You should not allow a step size greater than the 
>   difference in temperatures. (This exercise was based on a problem from C Programming 
>   Language).

I got the same results as the solution did, but I'm curios as to why their solution is more efficient (I'd presume it is). Anyone able to explain it to me? Their solution is first followed by mine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LOWER_LIMIT 0
#define HIGHER_LIMIT 50000

int main(void) {
    double fahr, cel;
    int limit_low = -1;
    int limit_high = -1;
    int step = -1;
    int max_step_size = 0;

    /* Read in lower, higher limit and step */
    while(limit_low < (int) LOWER_LIMIT) {
       printf("Please give in a lower limit, limit >= %d: ", (int) LOWER_LIMIT);
       scanf("%d", &limit_low);
    }
while((limit_high <= limit_low) || (limit_high > (int) HIGHER_LIMIT)) {
    printf("Please give in a higher limit, %d < limit <= %d: ", limit_low, (int) HIGHER_LIMIT);
    scanf("%d", &limit_high);
}
max_step_size = limit_high - limit_low;
while((step <= 0) || (step > max_step_size)) {
    printf("Please give in a step, 0 < step >= %d: ", max_step_size);
    scanf("%d", &step);
}

/* Initialise Celsius-Variable */
cel = limit_low;

/* Print the Table */
printf("\nCelsius\t\tFahrenheit");
printf("\n-------\t\t----------\n");
while(cel <= limit_high) {
    fahr = (9.0 * cel) / 5.0 + 32.0;
    printf("%f\t%f\n", cel, fahr);
        cel += step;
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

My solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LOW 0
#define HIGH 50000


int main(void)
{
int lower, higher, step, max_step;
float cel, fahren;

printf("\nPlease enter a lower limit, limit >= 0: ");
scanf("%d", &lower);

if (lower < LOW)
{
    printf("\nERROR: Lower limit must be >= 0.");
    exit(1);
}


printf("\nPlease enter a upper limit, limit <= 50000: ");
scanf("%d", &higher);

if (higher > HIGH)
{
    printf("\nERROR: Upper limit must be <= 50,000.");
    exit(1);
}

printf("\nPlease enter an increment amount, 0 < step <= 10: ");
scanf("%d", &step);

max_step = higher - lower;

if (step > max_step)
{
    printf("\nERROR: Step size cannot exceed difference between higher and lower limit.");
    exit(1);
}

printf("Celsuis \tFahrenheit\n");
printf("------- \t-----------\n\n");

cel = (float)lower;

while (cel < higher)
{
    fahren = cel * 9/5 + 32;
    printf("%f \t%f\n", cel, fahren);
    cel = cel + step;
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Besides the fact "+=" is less machine instructions than what I have.

Comment: What makes you say the first one is "more efficient"?

Comment: Why do you believe the site's solution is more efficient than yours, and by what measure?

Comment: The two solutions are almost the same...

Comment: @interjay ***Almost.*** Except that OP's solution is incorrect.

Comment: @H2CO3: Seems correct to me (considering that Michael's answer is incorrect).

Comment: Yes , i was mistaken, i have deleted the answer

Comment: @FredLarson I suppose nothing technically, besides the fact that he authored the question. A better question was probably, which is written with better practices

Comment: @Fred Larson, You could have given the option to delete the post, you was hurry to down-vote in the same time i tried to delete it, hope that no one has done it in your case

Comment: @Michael: Well, same result. You deleted the post and got your rep back. I know what you mean, though; I take downvotes hard myself. Which is one reason I rarely downvote anything.

Comment: "Their" answer probably isn't more efficient. They did some things that are nice like putting the user input into a loop so the user can try entering a valid value rather than just exiting right away. The contest should have had some statement regarding how the answers would be judged. The contests usually say what they're looking for (raw speed, small size, lowest memory usage, etc.). Without that it seems pretty subjective to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, which is more efficient... before making that claim we need some metrics, what are we talking about here? Run time? Binary size? 
Just a quick example… we can compile both solutions and run them with the "time" command and a worst case (0-50000 with a step of 1) to see what type of times we're using:

---

"Their" solution size:

```
text       data     bss     dec     hex filename
1937        276       8    2221     8ad a.out
```

"Their" solution running time:

```
user  0m 0.024s
sys   0m 0.601s
```

---

Your solution size:

```
text       data     bss     dec     hex filename
2054        276       8    2338     922 a.out
```

Your solution running time:

```
user   0m 0.025s
sys    0m 1.047s
```

---

So your solution takes longer and has a larger image size. Can we say now that "they" have a more efficient program? Not really, the `time` isn't totally accurate on this scale (and with other things happening in the system) so we'd need a number of runs. Averaged over four<sup>*</sup> runs:

```
// you
user    0.0178
system  0.9015
// "them"
user    0.016
system  0.914
```

So no, they are not really more "efficient" then you are.

There are some trivial things we can do to increase the "efficiency" here, but because the solutions are so similar, and the code is so trivial (a single stepping traversal) I'm not really sure if it matters all that much.

As far as "efficient" code size, you'll note that your `.text` size is larger than the other solution. Your messages are more verbose and readable, so you take a hit on size. Is that more efficient? Perhaps if size is important, but personally I think readability is more important unless we're talking an embedded solution.

<sup>* - you need a lot more runs and a more sensitive timing mechanism, but this is just a quick example</sup>

Comment: Thanks for all that information! :)